# Assembly language-How to make two inputted number as one?

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

I'm trying to do an assembly language programming with this condition:

```
    if age = 18 then write "You are of legal age" 
    else if age<18 then write "You are too young"
    else write "You should be working now"
```

Here's where I have a problem:

```
    mov ah,01h  "This is the first digit"
    int 21h
    mov bl,al
    mov ah,01h "This is the second'
    int 21h
```

When I input a two digit number, there are two different values of `AL`. I move the first value to `BL` to save it and I don't know what to do next. Can I ask how to make them combine as in when I input "17", it'll be 17h. I've read I need to subtract 30h but that only works with 0-9. I can't figure out what to do starting number 10 onwards. I'm using Tasm.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: What you *really* should do is to use buffered input (INT 21h; AH = 0Ah) to read both characters at a time. This will be far easier to implement and much more typical than reading a single character at a time and concatenating them.

Comment: "... I input "17", it'll be 17h" Are you sure the **h** suffix is correct? The text "17" translates to 17 in *decimal* but to 11h in *hexadecimal*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store two digit input as one, try this

```
num db 0     ;declare a variable to store the two digit input
ten db 10     ;declare a variable that holds a value 10

mov ah,01h  ;This is the first digit
int 21h
SUB al,48D     ;subtract 48D 
MUL ten        ;multiply with 10 because this digit is in ten's place
mov num,al    ;mov first digit input in num

mov ah,01h  ;This is the second digit
int 21h
SUB al,48D 
ADD num,al   ;add second digit to num
```

Now your two digit number is in variable `num`

**Note that i multiplied first digit input with 10 but i didn't multiply second digit input with anything because it's in one's place.**

Comment: "Can I ask how to make them combine as in when I input 17, it'll be 17h" You didn't answer this part of the question! Please add this to your answer and deserve my upvote. Requires just a few more lines of code...

Comment: @Fifoernik Edited my answer.

Comment: Rather than multiplying by 10, a real assembly pro would do a right-shift by 2 and two adds, *e.g.*, `lea xx, [xx+xx*4]; add xx, xx`.

Comment: @CodyGray: That's a huge PITA in 16-bit code, especially if you avoid using 32-bit addressing modes.  In 16-bit code that can assume 286, I'd be inclined to write `sub al, '0'` / `imul bx, ax, 10` / get next digit / ....  This of course leaves high garbage in BH, but we don't care about that.  ([`imul r8, r8, imm8`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IMUL.html) is not available.)  However, LEA does let you convert from ASCII to integer at the same time: `lea bx, [eax + eax*4 - '0'*5]`.  \@amazing: Either way, don't write it to memory until you're done computing it. That's what registers are for.

Comment: Also, am I the only person that finds it distracting/confusing to write decimal constants as `48D`?  I mean, my brain wants it to be a hex constant, since it's a mix of numbers and hex digits (specifically the D).  Especially in this case, when `'0'` (or even `30h`) or would be a clearer way to write it.

Comment: Oh, right, because scale-index-base addressing isn't available with 16-bit code. I always forget that, never having actually written any 16-bit code! You could still do `shr ax, 2` / `add ax, ax` / `add ax, ax`, though... This should still be faster than `mul` or `imul`, unless your bottleneck is the speed of instruction fetching, where a single instruction would better than three. But that would really only be the case on the 8088, 8086, or 386SX. On 286, instruction prefetching *should* be fast enough that it is dwarfed by the runtime of `mul`, but less clear without testing.